# Jekyll: div class not in CSS

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I am currently building a blog using the Jekyll static site generator and Github Pages. I would like to eventually work directly on the CSS and HTML and get rid of Jekyll altogether.

In one of the `div` elements in my site I see that the class `language-plaintext` is assigned. However this class does not occur in the CSS. Where does this class come from ?

Comment: maybe this can help? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-opensource-java/issues/1086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `language-plaintext` class is applied to Markdown code blocks [1] by Jekyll build process.  An example of Markdown code block

````
```
Hello World!
```
````

Jekyll provides a pluggable system [2] for giving code blocks CSS styling based on the code block language (e.g JavaScript, Python).  I believe this code highlighting feature is what uses the `language-plaintext` class.

Here is an example with javascript code block

````
```javascript
hello world
```
````

generates

```
<div class="language-javascript highlighter-rouge"><div class="highlight"><pre class="highlight"><code><span class="nx">hello</span> <span class="nx">world</span>
```

Note the `class="language-javascript`

[1] https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks

[2] https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/

Comment: Thanks. On a more general note, does the Jekyll build process actually handle the Markdown-to-HTML conversion, or is this something more intrinsic to markdown itself?

Comment: @user32882 In Jekyll, you can specify the "Markdown render" that Jekyll uses to do the Markdown-to-HTML.  I believe the default is "kramdown" [1].  In my past project, we extended Jekyll's markdown rendering engine to also process AsciiDoc [2].

[1] https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/
[2] https://asciidoc.org/